# Webpack file-loader template placeholders

Tags: webpack

being new to webpack i'm having a bit of trouble with a pretty simple (i guess) issue.

I'm using the file-loader for images and it works pretty fine using its default template placeholder (ex: ***file?name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]***).

What i'd like to achieve, though, is making that parameter 'dynamic', such as modifying on the fly with a function the ***[path]*** variable (ex: '*src/assets/img/folder*'--> '*img/folder*').

How can i do that? Do i require a plugin for that?

TIA

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Placeholders is part of the [Webpack LoaderUtils](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils) and looks like this is not customizable.

Comment: Thanks. Also, i noticed that for the specific use case **'src/assets/img/folder**'--> **'img/folder'** one can actually use the _context_ query parameter.